# Symfony2 differentiate user types in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

what is the way to differentiate users with FOSUserBundle?
For example: I have a user called "standard" that is related to an entity "Anagrafic" and access is redirected to the route "/ user /" as the user "admin" is not linked to any entity and access route is redirected to "/ admin /".
Can I keep the same user within the same entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To differentiate users in FOUserBundle, you must use ROLES, here is a full tutorial.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html
you don't need to add another entity.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But having a one-to-many relationship between "Anagrafic" and "user" and where the personal data refer only to the user "standard", you don't create inconsistency between the entities creating user "admin" in the same entity? And how can I target users with different roles in different routes?